# In jquery flot chart, highlight only one particular grid line

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using jquery flot chart to create a line chart. What I am not able to figure out is that how to change color of any one particular grid line.
The whole thing - The chart shows the sensor readings. There are total of 4 different readings like - very low, low, high, very high. I want to highlight the grid lines corresponding to these four threshold values. 
I am also providing a dummy image about what I really want to do --

[This is the dummy I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijlu9.png)

The black line in this image is the grid color of that particular line(sorry for my bad drawing). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the grid property `markings` like this:

```
$.plot("#YourPlotDiv", YourPlotSeries, {
    grid: {
        markings: [{ color: "#FFFF00", lineWidth: 1, yaxis: { from: 186, to: 186} },
                   { color: "#FF0000", lineWidth: 1, yaxis: { from: 191, to: 191} }]
    },
    ... further properties ...
});
```

In this example you have 2 gridlines marked which are at 186 and 191. If `from` and `to` are different and you would remove the `lineWidth` property, then you would mark an area.

Here is a woring fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyPxZ/

Comment: You can also supply an `xaxis: {...}` option to each marking if you want to mark an area (which gives a bit more control than just changing the size of the area), but leaving the option out will make the line stretch across the entire plot.